# Ошибка pip install tensorflow

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

Использую python последней версии. При установке `pip install tensorflow` возникает ошибка:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Как испроавить эту ошибку? Заранее спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он может не устанавливаться из-за вашей версии Питона , как я помню там Питон 3.5 - 3.7
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
И ваш pip должен быть обновлен